# Adding states and using them inside react component functions

Tags: reactjs

I have some rect componets whihc are just functions, I have posted a part of one of my components below

```
.....

const useStyles = makeStyles(presentationStyle);

export default function PresentationPage() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  });
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <Header
        brand="...."
        links={<HeaderLinks dropdownHoverColor="info" />}
        fixed
        color="transparent"
        changeColorOnScroll={{
          height: 400,
          color: "info"
        }}
      />
.....
```

Now, I need to use states and functions inside such function components, can someone give me a hint how to write them there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useState` hook from react. check the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html